# How i can fix this error (Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: apt, ssh, kubernetes

When I used this command

```
kubectl get nodes
```

I got this error

```
Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "kubernetes")

I used Ubuntu 20.04
Docker  20.10.14
kubeadm is already the newest version (1.23.5-00).
kubectl is already the newest version (1.23.5-00).
kubelet is already the newest version (1.23.5-00).
kubernetes-cni is already the newest version (0.8.7-00)